# Fazer o valor acumulativo no laço

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loop, for

```
var previsto = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $(".previsto").length ; i++)
{ 
    previsto[i] =  $(".previsto").eq(i).text();
}
```

Preciso pegar o próximo valor somando o anterior, para ter um acúmulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var previsto = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $(".previsto").length ; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
      previsto[i] =  $(".previsto").eq(i).text();
    else
      previsto[i] =  previsto[i-1] + $(".previsto").eq(i).text();
}
```

Para somar inteiros utilize a função parseInt.
Exemplo completo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>eq demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>20</div>
<div>4</div>

<script>
var previsto = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $("div").length ; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
      previsto[i] =  parseInt($("div").eq(i).text());
    else
      previsto[i] =  parseInt(previsto[i-1]) + parseInt($("div").eq(i).text());

}
console.log(previsto);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neste caso ele agrupa os valores

Comment: Ex: 20 , 4  Retronara 204. Quero que ele some os valores 20, 4 = 24

Comment: use a função parseInt

Comment: var previsto = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $(".previsto").length ; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
      previsto[i] =  parseInt($(".previsto").eq(i).text());
    else
      previsto[i] =  parseInt(previsto[i-1]) + parseInt($(".previsto").eq(i).text());
    
}
console.log(previsto);

Comment: Obrigado parceiro, resolveu o meu problema!

Comment: ok. marque a resposta como correta :)